# URL Creating using C# Microsoft .net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a site "www.pingplants.org". I need to create a url like "www.pingplants.org/register" for my register.aspx page instead of "www.pingplants.org/register.aspx"

Answer (score 2):

You can use UrlRouting feature in .net 4.0

[Url routing for web forms](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)